# Not entering SQL if statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I have a problem with entering an if statement in SQL Server.

I tried wrapping the if inner statements in BEGIN END blocks but no luck.

```
if (CHARINDEX(',', @Configs, 0) = 0)
    print 'Single config detected'
    begin
        if (@configAlreadyExists = 0)
        begin
            print 'Cofnig ' + @Configs + ' isn''t in the Health Check config display list, checking if it exists in table...'
            if not exists (select 1 from table where ConfigKey = @Configs)
                begin 
                    print 'Cofnig ' + @Configs + ' doesn''t exist in table, add the config first.'
                end
            else
                begin
                    print 'Cofnig ' + @Config + ' exists in table, adding config for Health Check display.'
                end
        end
    end
```

If I enter any string I would expect to eventually see the exists or doesn't exist in table printout, but I don't.

The only printout I see is 'Single config detected'.

Comment: I assume @configAlreadyExists is 0

Comment: As it stands your first `if` statement is *only* going to affect your print statement, without a `begin` and `end` it only applies to the next single statement. To test further you need to provide a [mcve] as we don't have enough information about the parameters and data you are using to provide useful advice.

Comment: Generally it is best to avoid if-statements in the sql. This is business logic and it belongs in your compiled code, not your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks suggest one of two things - an error during posting or use of a database engine that is not sql server. Assume the former but many posters don't know what database engine they use.

Your first "begin" is likely not correctly placed. You probably meant to do:

```
if charindex() = 0 
begin
   print ...
   if @configAlreadyExists = 0 
   begin 
      ... 
   end 
end
```

As it stands right now, a little effort at formatting makes the flow more obvious

```
if (CHARINDEX(',', @Configs, 0) = 0)
    print 'Single config detected'

begin
   if (@configAlreadyExists = 0)
   begin
      print 'Cofnig ' + @Configs + ' isn''t in the Health Check config display list, checking if it exists in table...'
      if not exists (select 1 from table where ConfigKey = @Configs)
         print 'Cofnig ' + @Configs + ' doesn''t exist in table, add the config first.'
      else 
         print 'Cofnig ' + @Config + ' exists in table, adding config for Health Check display.'
    end
end
```

I removed the inner-most (and not needed) begin/end statements to make things more clear and more compact.

Comment: the triple backticks are not valid in any DBMS. They are a way of formatting code blocks as an alternative to indenting. In this case they doubled them up though so the redundant backticks appear visible in the code displayed to us.